# Несколько модальных окон

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с модальными окнами. Допустим у меня есть главное окно, в котором имеется ComboBox, при выборе одного из пункта должно открываться новое окно. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class ModalTest extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            ObservableList<String> options =
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            "Option 1",
                            "Option 2",
                            "Option 3"
                    );

            Stage dialog = new Stage();
            dialog.setWidth(100);
            dialog.setHeight(100);
            dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);

            comboBox.setOnAction(event -> dialog.showAndWait());

            HBox box = new HBox(comboBox);

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));

            primaryStage.setWidth(400);
            primaryStage.setHeight(300);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как в контроллере это прописать?

Comment: В моем коде в контроллере прописано всего лишь: dialog.showAndWait(), в Вашем же может быть какая угодно логика.